# Using COALESCE but the column is still updated

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, coalesce

The objective is, if `$_POST['password']` is empty, do not update the password column but it is.

```
try {
        $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE users SET email = :email, password = COALESCE(NULLIF(:password, ""), password) WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $stmt->bindValue(':user_id', (int) $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $_POST['email'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT), PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $_SESSION['success'] = 'User updated successfully.';
        header('Location: '.DIRADMIN.'user.php');
        exit;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $_SESSION['error'] = 'An error occurred while updating the user.';
        error_log($e->getMessage(), 0);
    }
```

Any thoughts?

Edit:
In my example I am using `COALESCE` to return the first non-NULL string. So if `NULLIF` returns NULL because :password equals to "", then the first non-NULL string should be the value of the column password.

Comment: The problem is that you call `password_hash` even if the password is empty. The hashed password won't be an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're binding `:password` to the result of `password_hash`. When you hash an empty password, the result is not an empty string. Try:

```
$stmt->bindValue(':password', 
                 empty($_POST['password']) ? '' : password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT), 
                 PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: Thank you for bringing that to my attention and +1 for the Ternary Operator.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would not delegate this kind of check to your database code; rather I would probably use php before writing to the database; that way you avoid making an unnecessary database connection.

For example something like:

```
if (isset($_POST['password']) && !empty($_POST['password'])) {
    // write to the database
} else {
    // some error logic to flash the error back to the user
}
```

Comment: A database connection will always be necessary but not all columns will necessarily be updated (e.g., password column).

Comment: Ah I see, so this is for when a user updates their existing profile - makes sense. In which case, I would still check in php whether there is anything in `$_POST['password']` and then leave `password` out of your `SET` statement altogether if it's empty. In this bit `COALESCE(NULLIF(:password, ""), password)` I think you're intending the second `password` to represent the original password, but I don't think you can refer to original values in `SET` statements by their column titles. I may be wrong though.

Comment: @d0ug7a5 You definitely can refer to original values in `SET` statements. For instance, if you want to increment a column, you can use `SET col = col + 1`. This is very common.